Kafka consumer keeps getting records on poll after eviction from group
My application polls records from a MSK Kafka cluster. The application maintains offset of each partition and hence has disabled autocommit. It actually never commits offset as it persists offset to internal data store.
In production, we observed duplicate records. The duplicate records don't stop until we restart the instance with zombie consumer (evicted from group but keeps polling). A consumer turns to zombie when it fails to send heartbeats. This typically happens due to IAM authentication issues in MSK which sometime lasts for longer time.
On further digging, I found that the partitions that are assigned to zombie consumer are assigned to other active consumers, but the zombie consumers poll continue to return the records.
The question is - should a zombie consumer get records on poll?
I have been able to reproduce it locally. Here is my local setup with issue reproduced:

A single broker (docker image) with three different external port.
Create one topic with two partitions
Toxiproxy proxies these port.
Two consumers (subscribed to the topic) each connecting one of the proxied port with session timeout set to 10 seconds
Introduce latency in one of the proxy to evict one of the consumer from the group
Produce some messages for each partition
Both the consumer keep getting the messages

Kafka broker
docker run -d --name kafka-container \
    -e KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=yes \
    -e KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=1 \
    -e KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=broker,controller \
    -e KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER \
    -e KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1 \
    -e KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@localhost:9094 \
    -e KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL1:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL2:PLAINTEXT \
    -e KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9093,EXTERNAL1://:29093,EXTERNAL2://:39093,CONTROLLER://:9094 \
    -e KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=EXTERNAL://localhost:9092,EXTERNAL1://localhost:29092,EXTERNAL2://localhost:39092,PLAINTEXT://$CONTAINER_NAME:9092 \
    -e ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes \
    -e KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID=5e-ZWJELQjCqW2n3bwMTWg \
    -e KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=false \
    -p "9092:9093" \
    -p "29093:29093" \
    -p "39093:39093" \
    bitnami/kafka:latest

Toxiproxy proxies
toxiproxy-cli create -l localhost:29092 -u localhost:29093 zombie_consumer_scenario_healthy_proxy

toxiproxy-cli create -l localhost:39092 -u localhost:39093 zombie_consumer_scenario_unhealthy_proxy

Kafka Console consumer
kafka-console-consumer --group test-cg --topic test --consumer-property enable.auto.commit=false --consumer-property session.timeout.ms=10000 --bootstrap-server localhost:29092

kafka-console-consumer --group test-cg --topic test --consumer-property enable.auto.commit=false --consumer-property session.timeout.ms=10000 --bootstrap-server localhost:39092

Latency Toxic
toxiproxy-cli toxic add -t latency -n myToxic -a latency=10000 -a jitter=50 zombie_consumer_scenario_unhealthy_proxy

As a solution, I am thinking of taking control of partition assignment in my application. However, I believe kafka consumer should not poll should not return records after eviction from the group.

Sounds to me like a proxy misconfiguration (the group leave request isn't making it to the group coordinator). Can you please test without it? Also try the official Apache Kafka docker image please

Thanks for the reply @OneCricketeer. The zombie doesn't leave the group voluntarily. Its heartbeat fails and hence consumer group coordinator kick it out. This is something which can happen in real world and these proxies are just mimicking it.

Is there a JIRA ticket for it? What other versions of the broker or client have you tried?

I am in the process of logging a ticket as I am waiting for my ASF account to log Jira. Currently I tested it 3.9.0 version of kafka consumer. Any version that you think I should be trying with?
Also, I will try with official image of kafka broker and post the results here.

Tried with kafka consumer version 3.7.1 but the same results. Also logged the following issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-18143
